# Is $z \mapsto \operatorname{Re}(z)$ a linear map?

Tags: complex-numbers, linear-transformations

I am referring here to the function that maps a complex number $z$ to its real part.

This may be an obvious question, but it seems to me that it is; however, I wouldn't really know how to go about proving it in any kind of rigorous fashion. Note that this isn't something that I *need* to do for any kind of assignment, but simply a curiosity as I'm studying complex variables at the moment and my textbook is more "application-oriented," and thus does not go into much detail on such matters. Naturally, I'd want to show that this function preserves additivity and scalar multiplication, and as far as I've seen, that has been the case. I would like to be able to conclusively say, though, that this is, indeed, a linear mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map $\operatorname{Re}: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is a linear map when we *regard $\Bbb C$ as a real vector space*. Indeed, we can write any element $z \in \Bbb C$ as $x + iy$ (that is, decompose it w.r.t. the *real* basis $\{1, i\}$). Then, for any $a, b \in \Bbb R$ and $x + iy, x' + iy' \in \Bbb C$, we have $$\operatorname{Re} [a(x + iy) + b(x' + iy')] = ax + bx' = a \operatorname{Re} (x + iy) + b \operatorname{Re} (x' + iy') .$$

On the other hand, this is *not* a linear map when we regard $\Bbb C$ as a *complex* vector space (that is, $\operatorname{Re}$ is not *complex-linear*). Indeed, we have
$$\operatorname{Re}(i) = 0 \neq i = i \operatorname{Re} 1 .$$

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. Now, naturally, I am curious about Im$(z)$! Indeed, following your counterexample, it seems that Im$(i)=i \ne 0=i$Im$(1)$. But, perhaps I've misunderstood it...

Comment: Yes, you're exactly correct about $\operatorname{Im}$. In fact, any field $\Bbb F$ regarded as a vector space over itself (and hence, by choosing any isomorphism, any vector space $\Bbb V$ of dimension $1$ over a given field) has basis $\{1\}$ and so the only linear maps $\Bbb F \to \Bbb F$ (or $\Bbb V \to \Bbb V$) are the scalar maps $x \mapsto a x$ for $a \in \Bbb F$.

Answer (score 3):

If $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2=x_2+iy_2$, then for each $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb R$ we have
$$
Re(c_1z_1+c_2z_2)=c_1x_1+c_2x_2=c_1Re(z_1)+c_2Re(z_2).
$$
Note that this fails in general for $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb C$.